# Netsuite Transaction Body Field referencing custom and system field

Tags: sql, netsuite

We have created a custom drop-down menu on transactions, that lists every contact (record). I want to create a secondary custom body field (Inline/Disabled display type) that shows the selected contact and the CURRENTLY* selected ship-to address.

*not the default address.

I can do this in the PDF/HTML forms, but for transparency's sake I would like to be able to come up with a solution using the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field of type Text Area and concatenate the two fields with a line break in between to display what you want.  When creating the field make sure you uncheck the Store Value option to make it a dynamic field, select Disabled under the Display tab, then in the Validation & Defaulting tab check the formula option and use the following formula (replace field references as appropriate)

```
{custbody_contact_field} || chr(13) || {shipaddress}
```

You could also simply modify the form so that the ship to address is displayed on the main fields section directly after your custom contact field rather than daoubling up, if this suits your purpose.